# How to correctly include sass Foundation partials using node modules with include paths

Tags: npm, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to set include paths up correctly with npm sass so that I can access Foundation in my project. If I fire:

```
sass -I node_modules/foundation-sites/scss --watch src/scss/style.scss:assets/css/style.css
```

I expect this to then allow me to get certain aspects of Foundation such as:

```
@import 'grid/grid';
```

Or foundation in it's sass entirity through:

```
@import 'foundation';
```

But attempting this returns an error "File to import not found or unreadable". The path does appear to be correct. What's currently incorrect with my import paths?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct path?  To import `grid/grid`, the path to it would have to be `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/grid/_grid.scss`, relative from where you ran the `sass` command from.

Comment: So the import path should be to a specific file, rather than a folder? I have tried what you suggested, and I still get the same error. Is there a better way to include foundation sass and then pick what I want? I'm trying to avoid copying over files into my own project's folder and just keep it within node_modules.

Comment: No, it is to a directory, I am asking you to double check that the path you're using is correct.  If you're using a relative path, it is considered to be relative from where you ran the command from.